# Changing default catch code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I would like to find a way to tell Android Studio what code should be used for Unhandled Exception errors when selecting "add 'catch' clauses.

The default code looks something like this:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code will show up after the user selects "add 'catch' clause" at the dropdown menu in a UnhandledException error:

[image: dropdown menu option]

I'm trying to set up a different code but I do not know how to change this setting in Android Studio or whether this is possible.